# Подскажите плагин в Webstorm с подсказками для стилизации при помощи material ui

Tags: javascript, webstorm, material-ui

Всем привет. Я решил попробовать использовать для стилизации material ui. Есть ли какой-нибудь плагин с подсказками для стилей в Webstorm? Видел что-то подобное у VS code.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно работать без всяких плагинов в [2021.1 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/nextversion/), см. [WEB-48038](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48038)

Comment: Спасибо) Правда, эта версия только вчера вышла) До этого у меня была 2020.3